# Convert byte (java data type) value to bits (a string containing only 8 bits)

Tags: java, byte

I need to convert a value declared as a byte data type into a string of 8 bits. Is there any Java library method that can do this? For example, it should take in -128 and output "10000000". Also, input -3 should give "11111101". (I converted these by hand.)

*Before you assume this has been answered many times, please let me explain why I am confused.*

*The name "byte" is a little ambiguous. So, it's been difficult following other answers. For my question, `byte` is referring to the **java data type** that takes up 8 bits and whose value ranges from -128 to 127. I also don't mean an "array of bytes". My question is about converting a single value into its 8-bit representation only. Nothing more.*

I've tried these:

```
byte b = -128;  //i want 10000000
Integer.toBinaryString(b); //prints 11111111111111111111111110000000
Integer.toString(b, 2); //prints -10000000
```

If there's no built-in method, can you suggest any approach (maybe bit shifting)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try

```
Integer.toBinaryString(b & 0xFF);
```

this gives a floating length format e.g. `4` -> `100`. There seems to be no standard solution to get a fixed length format, that is `4` -> `00000100`. Here is a one line custom solution (prepended with `0b`)

```
String s ="0b" + ("0000000" + Integer.toBinaryString(0xFF & b)).replaceAll(".*(.{8})$", "$1");
```

Comment: This seems to work fine. Thanks a lot!! I wonder why they couldn't just have a `Byte.toBinaryString` method?!?

Comment: I agree. First option I tried (without success) was Byte.toBinaryString.

Comment: I can write a function to ensure the result is padded with zeros up to 8 characters for positive numbers. However, your regex works but I dont understand it. Can u explain?

Comment: I'll try. ".*(.{8})$" means "any text that ends with any 8 chars". (.{8}) - last 8 chars is group #1 (since theres not other group in regex). $1 means "replace with group #1". All in all - take all text and replace it with the last 8 chars. :)

Comment: I do understand now. I've learned something else today. Thanks.

Comment: Nice use of patterns here. Back on the day, I would have gone with `DecimalFormat`; but it is always nice to see different ways of doing something.